# ¿Cómo validar si existe un usuario en laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, api

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto aparte y necesitaba una api, me enteré que se puede crear una con laravel asi que la creé y configuré las rutas y todas las cosas y ya en el formulario que tengo aparte puedo enviar los datos a la ruta. Mi duda es como puedo tomar esos datos que son estos

```
<form
                    class="col-12"
                    id="formulario"
                    action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/userSesion"
                    method="post"
                >
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="usuario">Nombre de Usuario</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            class="form-control"
                            id="usuario"
                            name="usuario"
                            placeholder="Nombre de usuario"
                            required
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="pass">Contraseña</label>
                        <input
                            type="password"
                            class="form-control"
                            id="pass"
                            name="pass"
                            placeholder="Contraseña"
                            required
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                        <button
                            type="submit"
                            value=""
                            class="btn btn-success"
                            href="ejemplo.html"
                        >
                            Entrar
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

pueda validar en un controlador que el usuario existe y devolverme algún valor para yo poder aceptar el usuario y enviarlo a la página de ser correcto los datos, sino decir que es inválido. Este es el controlador que recibe el valor de los input del form

```
public function compare(Request $request)
{
    $nombre = $request->input("usuario");
    $pass = $request->input("pass");

    
}
```

Comment: Por ahora nada porque con laravel estoy muy crudo pero si, esa es la idea, validar usuario. El sistema solo tendrá un usuario que será el administrador pero necesito hacerle ese login para el

Comment: Solo tendrias que validar con el email o un username tu "action" solo necesitas poner '/api/userSesion', en cuestion a la validacion es mas simple de lo que crees tanto solo hacer $user = User::where('username', '=', $request->get('usuario'))->first(); y validas si es true no te dedje registrarlo en caso contrario lo registras

Comment: Lo que intenté es lo que está en el controlador

Comment: Y cuando me devuelva true cómo hago para que me redirija a la otra página que quiero? porque solo me lleva a la ruta pero a la otra página html que quiero

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto:

```
public function compare(Request $request) {
    $input = $request->all();

    if(User::where("name",$input['usuario'])->where("password",$input['pass'])->first()){
        return view('welcome'); //Inicio de sesión correcto
    }else{
        return view('login'); //Credenciales incorrectas
    }
}
```

No sé qué tanto conocimiento tengas de Laravel pero User es el modelo de la tabla usuario, si quieres realizarlo directo solo sería:

```
\DB::table("users")->where("name",$input['usuario'])->where("password",$input['pass'])->first()
```

Comment: En este caso es necesario validar el usuario y el pass. y dd('Usuario y pass son correctos') no necesita nada mas eso es solo para imprimir pantalla (para ver que vas por el camino correcto)